# Seemingly Simple Probabilistic Inequality Question

Tags: probability, inequality, random-variables, holder-inequality

Let's assume all random variables here take positive values. All RVs will be represented in capital letters and constants in lower case. First, we know that
$$\big| \mathbb{E}[A] - \mathbb{E}[B] \big| \le k$$

Now we also know that for RVs $M$ and $N$, $\mathbb{E}[M] = 1$ and $\mathbb{E}[N]=1$. Also $M$ and $N$ are bounded.
I am trying to show (or find a counter-example) that
$$\big| \mathbb{E}[AM] - \mathbb{E}[BN] \big| \le kc$$
In other words $\big| \mathbb{E}[AM] - \mathbb{E}[BN] \big|$ is on the order of $\big| \mathbb{E}[A] - \mathbb{E}[B] \big|$.

So far the most promising direction seems to be use Hölder's inequality where we have that $$\mathbb{E}[|AM|]\le\mathbb{E}[|A|]\sup|M|\le \mathbb{E}[|A|]\cdot h$$ and similarly $$\mathbb{E}[|BN|]\le\mathbb{E}[|B|]\sup|N|\le \mathbb{E}[|B|]\cdot l$$

However, the subtraction is throwing things off with my straight-forward calculation. I was hoping someone had a better idea for how to progress, or of course a counter-example?

Comment: With no condition on c, it will always be trivially true, use $E[|BN|]\ge 0$

Comment: @herb_steinberg would you care to elborate?

Comment: $|E[AM]-E[BN]|=s$ unknown but finite, so $c=k/s$ will do.

Comment: I'm sorry @herbsteinberg I'm just not seeing it. If you set $c=ks$ in my inequality above then you get $|E[AM] - E[BN]|\le k^2/s$. Is that right? and you're saying $s = |E[AM] - E[BN]|$. I don't quite follow.

Comment: My error.  s=kc, so c=s/k.

Comment: @herbsteinberg I see what you're saying but then that takes the $k$ out of the inequality. This is to say your $c$ depends of $k$, so doesn't work. The point is that we want that $|E[A] - E[B]| = k$ is small implies that $|E[AM] - E[BN]|$ is small, but basically all you're saying is that $|E[AM] - E[BN]|=s$ no matter what $k$ is.

Comment: You need to define "small" for c to be meaningful..

Comment: Only thing we meed is that $c$ doesn't depend on $k$